# Static box in another static box on wxpython

Tags: wxpython

How would i implement a static box within another static box in wxpython ontop of the panel?

I am trying to accomplish this because i am grouping buttons for different things.

thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use **[`StaticBoxSizer`](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.StaticBoxSizer-class.html)**

```
import wx

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)

        self.box1 = wx.StaticBox(self.panel, label="One")      
        self.box2 = wx.StaticBox(self.panel, label="Two")

        self.box_sizer = wx.StaticBoxSizer(self.box1, wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.box_sizer.Add(self.box2, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.box_sizer, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.panel.SetSizerAndFit(self.sizer)

        self.Show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    win = MainWindow(None)
    app.MainLoop()
```